# New solenoid is stuck

Tags: ford, f-250, solenoid

I just replaced the solenoid for a 1984 f250 pickup, and after starting it I noticed a strange noise. I turned the key off, but it was still cranking. Is there any reason why a brand new solenoid should get stuck?

[image]
The circled wires are the ones I touched together. They both came off the solenoid.

Comment: I take it this is a starter mounted solenoid?

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 the starter and solenoid are separate if that's what you mean.

Comment: If this is a fender mount solenoid (the 84 could have either, depending on the engine used), then it's not your solenoid which is the problem. Most likely it's the start itself which is not disengaging the flexplate.

Comment: so i need a new starter?

Comment: Not right off the bat. Could just be the starter needs adjusting. You could also see about taking it apart to see what is causing it to stick. Starter motors are pretty simple beasts. You just have to ensure the brushes go back in correctly.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Is there a positive or negative side or are they interchangeable? I think I might have the solenoid upside down.

Comment: Are you saying that the engine started, then you turned the ignition off so that the engine should stop, but you could hear the starter still turning the engine over?  Or had the starter disengaged from the flywheel, but the started was still turning?  Either way, how did you stop the starter turning?  Did you have to disconnect the battery?

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 It sounds to me that the op is saying that the starter was still getting power after the ignition was turned off.  If that is the case, surely it can’t be the starter at fault, it must either be the solenoid (relay) or the ignition switch providing power to the solenoid.  Am I misunderstanding it?

Comment: @HandyHowie - You may be correct. The fender mounted solenoid is easily tested. With no power applied to it, check for continuity between the two big posts. If there is continuity, the solenoid is bad. You can also apply power between the two small posts while checking continuity between the two big posts to see if the circuit is broken when power is disconnected. If the continuity is there when power is applied and not when taken away, then it should be good.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 the solenoid may only have the issue when it switches a large current due to the contacts fusing together.

Comment: @HandyHowie - If they are fusing together when actuated, they'll stay fused together after there's no more power to the actuator. If they are fused, continuity will be there. Like I said, it's easily checked. TBH, I've never seen these fuse like you're talking, though. A starter solenoid, whether fender mounted or starter mounted, will usually go bad by wearing out - faces of the copper will become burnt where they won't pass power any longer. I don't believe they'll fuse because copper passes the current without heating up significantly. Just the brief arc at contact, on or off.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 I just started/stopped it with no problems so at this point I have no idea what's going on.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 just got off the phone with someone who thinks the starter is crystalized and welded and that I need a new one.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are suggesting that the starter motor was still getting power after the ignition was turned off, so the starter was still turning by electrical power.

If this is the case, it can’t be the starter that is at fault, but must be either the solenoid or the ignition switch that is at fault.

You need to identify whether the thin wire on the solenoid that connects back to the ignition switch has 12V on it when this happens.

If there is 12V on the thin wire when the ignition is not in the start position, then the ignition key is faulty.  If there is not 12V on the thin wire, then the solenoid is faulty.

I have repaired a vehicle where the ignition key was sticking a little in the starter position, rather than springing fully back into position 2.  One other symptom was that that things like the radio were not working when the key stuck in the start position.

Comment: Your first sentence is correct. I had taken the key all the way out, and it was still cranking so I unhooked the battery to make it stop.

Comment: Does it matter which side positive and negative go on?

Comment: Also, if the solenoid was disconnected, is there any reason why the starter should crank when the battery leads are touched together?

Comment: Can you add a photo of the solenoid, so that I understand what you mean by the positive and negative?  Do you mean the positive and negative for controlling the solenoid?

Comment: So you disconnected the two thick wires from the solenoid.  Which battery leads are you touching together?

Comment: I'll upload a photo.

Comment: If you touch the 2 thick wires that you have circled together, I would expect the starter motor to run.  That is what the starter solenoid does, it connects those wires together when you turn the ignition to the start position.

Answer (score 0):

I repaired the same problem on a 1977 Ford van. The starter relay would not shut off. It burned out 2 starters and 2 relays. I used the wiring diagram to discover a connector on the top of the transmission. That connector had 2 wire pairs: one from the reversing lamp circuit and one pair from the neutral safety switch circuit. The wire insulation was crumbling and it caused 12 volts to enter the starter relay. I repaired the 4 wires and the problem is ... gone.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got a hold of my mechanic and he said the solenoid is bad, so I got a new one and the problem seems to be gone.